# How to use all property values of an object as a type?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a class to handle `CustomEvent`s in my app. Here's what it looks like so far:

```
export const EVENT_NAMES = {
  TEST_EVENT: 'HELLO_WORLD',
  THIS_IS: 'REALLY_HARD'
};

export type EventName = keyof typeof EVENT_NAMES;

export class Events {
  static on(eventName: EventName, eventHandler: Function): void {
    document.addEventListener(eventName, (e: CustomEvent): void => {
      eventHandler(e.detail);
    });
  }
}

/* 
    Want to do this, but TypeScript complains:
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 
    '"TEST_EVENT" | "THIS_IS"'. ts(2345)
*/   
Events.on(EVENT_NAMES.TEST_EVENT, () => {
  // handle the event
});
```

I want to enforce that any value passed to the `eventName` argument in `Events.on` is a valid event that belongs in `EVENT_NAMES`, which is the **value** of any property in that object, not the **key** of any prop. I can't quite figure out how to accomplish this, and if anyone has any pointers, that'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like the type of `EVENT_NAMES.TEST_EVENT` is `string`. Have you tried setting the value to `'HELLO_WORLD' as 'HELLO_WORLD'`?

Comment: @Wex that wouldn't work, as `type 'HELLO_WORLD' is not assignable to type 'TEST_EVENT' | 'THIS_IS'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your definition of `EventName` sets you up to use the keys from `EVENT_NAMES` as your argument, not the values. Second, the type of the values are strings. You can cast those using `as`:

```
const EVENT_NAMES = {
  TEST_EVENT: 'HELLO_WORLD',
  THIS_IS: 'REALLY_HARD'
} as const;

// 'HELLO_WORLD' | 'REALLY_HARD'
export type EventName = typeof EVENT_NAMES[keyof typeof EVENT_NAMES];
```

Now, this should work:

```
Events.on(EventNames.HELLO_WORLD, () => {});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I'd really like to avoid repetition of the values if possible. I'll be looking for a solution to this problem and will update the post if I find one.

Comment: Updated my answer with the new `as const` syntax introduced in TypeScript 3.4

Comment: :D! Thanks a ton, this is very helpful to me. Cheers!